# What is meant by an object's "state" in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Here is the context in which it is being used:

> "If all of the state of an object is private, then the object is
>   tamper-proof. Properties of the object can be replaced or deleted, but
>   the integrity of the  bject is not compromised."

This is from Crockford's *Javascript: The Good Parts*.

Comment: state would be the combo of properties and values on an object. those are actually never private, but you can use a function closure to modify an other-wise unreachable object.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_(computer_science)

Answer (score 1):

In software engineering, state is generally used to refer to all the values of all the properties/attributes of an object. In javascript it has the same meaning.